# Test for multiple words in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like so:

```
var str = "FacebookExternalHit and some other gibberish";
```

Now I have a list of strings to test if they exist in `str`. Here they are in array format:

```
var bots = ["FacebookExternalHit", "LinkedInBot", "TwitterBot", "Baiduspider"];
```

What is the fastest and/or shortest method to search `str` and see if any of the `bots` values are present? Regex is fine if that's the best method.

Comment: Just loop over the array.

Comment: Yeh I thought about doing that but it occurred to me there might be a shorted and easier way.

Comment: [A simple white-list](http://jsfiddle.net/n8t7gdbe/), though I'm not sure how fast it is compared to a loop.

Comment: @teemu here's a [test](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-array-prototype-some-for-substring-search). It's pretty biased, though... considering the input string...

Comment: @canon Well, your test case confirms my assumptions, a simple loop is often faster than any fancy array method. In the "regexp" case you would probably get faster code by caching the RegExp, in your test it's time-consuming to create a new array on each execution.

Comment: @Teemu I've updated to include a cached regex test (which obviously performs better). That said, in practice he's going to have to instantiate the regex. That overhead should be considered. If the OP actually stands to re-use the regex it makes more sense. Without more information, though... I couldn't say.

Answer (score 5):

Using `join` you can do:

```
var m = str.match( new RegExp("\\b(" + bots.join('|') + ")\\b", "ig") );
//=> ["FacebookExternalHit"]
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know that regex is necessarily the way to go here. Check out `Array.prototype.some()`

```js
var str = "FacebookExternalHit and some other gibberish";
var bots = ["FacebookExternalHit", "LinkedInBot", "TwitterBot", "Baiduspider"];
var isBot = bots.some(function(botName) {
  return str.indexOf(botName) !== -1;
});
console.log("isBot: %o", isBot);
```

A regular `for` loop is [even faster](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-array-prototype-some-for-substring-search):

```js
var str = "FacebookExternalHit and some other gibberish";
var bots = ["FacebookExternalHit", "LinkedInBot", "TwitterBot", "Baiduspider"];
var isBot = false;

for (var i = 0, ln = bots.length; i < ln; i++) {
  if (str.indexOf(bots[i]) !== -1) {
    isBot = true;
    break;
  }
}

console.log("isBot: %o", isBot);
```

Comment: just an easy way to iterate over each element, but I prefer your method of using `some` .